# CLR Stored Procedures: alternatives to SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart / SendResultsRow / SendResultsEnd?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, clr

A related question to a previous one regarding the same subject.
In a CLR stored procedure, I am bulding a collection of objects which represent a data set after a complex filtering.
This collection is then "translated" in a resulset with the SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart / SendResultsRow / SendResultsEnd loop and delivered.

Despite this works as it should, it doesn't feel optimal because of the loop etc.
Are there any better alternatives to, say, convert collections to SQL resultsets on the fly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody? I was hoping to find a few answers after a few days, but looks like I haven't been that lucky :-(

Comment: Anybody out there? :)
I am still using that approach, it is working fine so it is somehow OK. But it doesn't feel a clean solution and am looking forward to hearing other ideas.

Comment: Perhaps if you provided some code examples that would help

Answer (score 0):

The better alternative would be to organize the collection into a xml document.(which you can easily do it through .NET libraries) Then you can use sql node xml method to parse the xml document to return a resultset. you can use LINQ library to convert a collection to XML. The level of the design would change according to the context. but i found this way to be very efficient.